# Does anybody know what kind of tree is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

I saw this tree yesterday and I liked it. It is around 1.5 m. I did some search on internet and thought it might be Holly, but I'm not an expert on trees. So I wanted to ask you, does anyone know what kind of tree is this?

Location:The Netherlands[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a holly, similar to English holly ( at least that is that it is called in the US ) .There are different cultivars . It has been pruned to a tree shape .

Comment: Thank you for the answer.